# SPARQL - retrieve all preferred terms and their alternate forms in just one language

Tags: sparql

Beginner warning :) I am exploring the Eurovoc European multilingual database of concept keywords.

SPARQL endpoint can be accessed at http://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql

I wish to find all terms in it only for the Italian language and for each term I want to see the prefLabel but also if there are any alternate forms of that concept (altLabel).

My current query is:

```
select ?s ?plabel ?alabel where {
?s a skos:Concept .
?s skos:prefLabel ?plabel .
?s skos:altLabel ?alabel .
 FILTER (langMatches(lang(?plabel),"it"))
} limit 100
```

and it properly returns the prefLabel concepts but the altLabels are not related to them. What's wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you mean by "not related" - of course you also have to filter by Italian language for the alternative label? Why did you not do this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: also, you should consider cases when there is no such alternative label, thus, you should put the triple pattern into an `OPTIONAL` clause.

Comment: `select distinct ?s ?plabel ?alabel where {
?s a skos:Concept .
?s skos:prefLabel ?plabel .
OPTIONAL {?s skos:altLabel ?alabel .
FILTER (langMatches(lang(?alabel),"it"))}
 FILTER (langMatches(lang(?plabel),"it"))
} limit 100`

Comment: Thank you to all for pointing out my mistakes. As a beginner I was under the impression that the FILTER clause was applied to the whole select between curly braces, and yes I need to study the OPTIONAL clause too. You example works well. Thanks. Why don't you post it as a reply so I can vote it as a solution?